# How to use Core ML to analyse device motion values

Tags: coreml

I would like to implement Core-ML app to analyze **Device Motion**, I'm recording device motion values for some time and capturing the details into the JSON file. Now I want to analyze the data x, y, z values then I should give the result how the user using the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use Turi Create. It has an Activity Classification module that makes this very easy: https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/activity_classifier/

To learn more about this in detail, check out the book Machine Learning by Tutorials (disclaimer: I'm a co-author but did not write the chapters on activity classification).

Comment: Thank you, I will check.